# Data from one Excel workbook in Alteryx

Tags: excel, data-science, alteryx

I want to import data from an Excel workbook to Alteryx, where I do have around 100+ tabs but I need data only from specific tabs.

metadata are not common, unstructured data, around 2 million records, data formats are not common & data are not in tabular format.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like "lakh" or "lac" here. We're not all from India.

Comment: Thanks very much, James Z..noted. I will be more careful at the time of posting any questions.

Comment: This Alteryx macro might get you pretty close: https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Knowledge-Base/Read-in-Multiple-Excel-Files-with-Multiple-Tabs-that-have/ta-p/51145